# Как подключить lightGallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно подключить несколько галерей на одной странице
С id работает только первая, оно и понятно. А на классы не могу переключить, не работает.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<div id="gallery">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<script>
lightGallery(document.getElementById('gallery'), {
...
});
</script>
```

[пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/stopani/pen/JjmPZgv)

Comment: _на классы не могу переключить, не работает_ - в codepen примере всё работает

Comment: работает только первый блок, второй нет

Comment: @steep вам же дали внизу пример. посмотрите, там реализован вызов по классу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним из возможных решений этой проблемы может быть использование уникальных имен идентификаторов для каждого контейнера галереи и вызов функции lightGallery() для каждого отдельного идентификатора. В качестве альтернативы вы можете использовать селектор классов, чтобы настроить таргетинг на все контейнеры галереи и пройтись по ним, чтобы применить функцию lightGallery() к каждому из них.

Вот пример того, как вы могли бы реализовать первое решение:

```
<div id="gallery1">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<div id="gallery2">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<script>
lightGallery(document.getElementById('gallery1'), {
...
});

lightGallery(document.getElementById('gallery2'), {
...
});
</script>
```

В качестве альтернативы, вот пример того, как вы могли бы реализовать второе решение с помощью селектора классов:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/img1.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img2.jpg">
        <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
    </a>
    ...
</div>

<script>
const galleries = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery');
for (let i = 0; i < galleries.length; i++) {
  lightGallery(galleries[i], {
    ...
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Второй вариант я написал и тут смотрю у вас он точь в точь написан, пришлось удалять))